# Best approach to switch PartialView result that is displayed based on configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So right now if I want to change what partial view I display on a page based of off configuration I do the follow:

Config Item: 
    `<add key="InstanceOwner" value="companyName" />`

Call to render partial view:

```
 <div id="" class="sidebarBox side-box3">
      Html.RenderAction("ProductFeature", "Dashboard");
 </div>
```

Controller ActionResult:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 1)]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult ProductFeature(string viewName = InstnaceOwner+"ProductFeature")
{
  return PartialView(viewName);
}
```

I will name the partial views using a naming convention that is companyName-ProductFeature, the companies name will be variable. Doing it this way feels wrong and inefficient. I'm still really new to .NET MVC though and just want to know what the best approach to this is,Thanks!

Comment: Will you have more than one key like "InstanceOwner"? So will you have something like `<add key="CompanyA" value="companyNameAProductFeature" /><add key="CompanyB" value="companyNameBProductFeature" />` ?

Comment: No, the plan is to just change the value of the configuration key if I'm having to change which instance (which customer) the app is being used for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the plan is to just change the value of the configuration key if I'm
>   having to change which instance (which customer) the app is being used
>   for

Based on that comment then it could just be as simple as reading the config value and use that to determine which view to show. You don't need to accept any parameters for the controller method.

```
public ActionResult ProductFeature()
{
    var prefix = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InstanceOwner"];
    return PartialView(prefix+"ProductFeature");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of MVC are you using?

If i was you, i will get all the data soon as i enter the page controller (e.g. HomeController)

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new SomeViewModel();
        model.ProductFeature = InstnaceOwner + "ProductFeature"
        return View(model); 
    }
```

Then in the View, (index.cshtml)

```
     @Html.Partial("_ProductFeature", Model.ProductFeature)
```

and in the partial View (_ProductFeature.cshtml)

```
     @model string
     <span>Product Feature is @model</span>
```

Hope this answers your question

Comment: I'm using MVC3, we have not used view models at any point with in the app yet though.

Comment: I think ViewModel is quite good way to maintain the data between the controller and View, should look into it, I use it  in all my project.  Other way of doing is you can use ViewBag, you can find some reference here

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/WhatplusisplusViewData-2cplusViewBagplusandplusTem

Comment: That's a great resource thank you! Reading through it I can see what you mean. It may good if our team used to a method more like this.